# Autonomous two dimensional systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble because the question is very vague.

'Discuss the remaining cases for two-dimensional autonomous systems:
(a) $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda \neq 0$ for (i) two distinct eingenvectors $h_1 and h_2$ (ii) only one eigenvector $h_1$

(b) A a singular matrix sketch the solutions in all instances

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is talking about a system of the form
$ \dot{x} = A x$ where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix.  For example in (a(i))
the matrix is
$$\pmatrix{\lambda &0\cr 0 & \lambda\cr}$$
(can you prove that?)

The kind of discussion and sketch will be similar to what was discussed and sketched in the cases that have already been covered, something you have not told us.  You'll probably want to distinguish between $\lambda > 0$ and $\lambda < 0$.

Comment: The previous section of the book talks about what you listed and then: stable node, unstable node, saddle point, stable focus, unstable focus, and vortex

Comment: I think it means to describe what it would create